# Изменение значения текста в kivy после определённого действия пользователя

Tags: python, kivy

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал изучать kivy и никак не могу понять, как менять значение текста в Lable после определённого действия пользователя(например on_touch_move). Приведите, пожалуйста, простенький пример, чтобы я понял, как это делается. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
    Box:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            id: your_label
            text: 'First text...'

        Button:
            on_press:
                root.set_new_text_label()
            # Или так:
            # on_press:
            #    your_label.text = 'Second text...'
''')


class Box(BoxLayout):
    def set_new_text_label(self, *args):
        '''Устанавливает новый текст надписи, используя
        свойство text по её id.'''

        self.ids.your_label.text = 'Second text...'


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Box()


Test().run()
```